# Why can't we package custom AuthProvider in Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, oauth2, isv, namedcredentials, auth-provider

My `Managed Package` app connects to an external REST API. This API uses OAuth2. For easy connectivity, I planned on packaging a custom `AuthProvider` with all the app-specific settings like URLs and Client Id and Secret and then have a `NamedCredential` that is using it.

The problem I face is that **I cannot package an AuthProvider**, only a NamedCredential.

As a workaround, I create the `AuthProvider` and `NamedCredential` from an Admin-controlled Setup page using `Metadata API`. But by doing that the customer Admin sees the Client Id and Secret and could potentially misuse it to talk to the API using my Client Id.

**Why doesn't Salesforce allow us to package AuthProviders? At least the org-unspecific parts.**

*Note: I understand that read-only properties like URLs are org-specific but Salesforce could easily build `AuthProviders` to make that dynamic and only contain org independent info.*

Comment: If you create an idea, we'd vote for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Auth Provider is org specific. It has a **callback URL** where a connected app redirects after authentication and org get authcode and complete the rest authentication steps.

If salesforce allows **Auth Provider** to be packaged then redirect url will be same (same as packaging org) for all the subscriber orgs and it will redirect incorrectly to packaging org instead of subscriber org. This is the reason why salesforce can not allow packaging Auth. Provider.

Comment: How can we configure different callback URLs for the connected app in each subscriber org?

Comment: You don't have to configure it manually. Salesforce automatically create callback url with following pattern https://<Instance Url>/services/authcallback/<Auth provider name>

Comment: That’s not a real answer. Salesforce could just build auth providers in a way that it only contains org independent information

Comment: @SushantSrivastava what if I want to callback URL to be external site, say WordPress site?

Comment: @rahulgawale, could you please describe your scenario bit more.

Comment: @SushantSrivastava We are trying to create a managed package that will sync data between salesforce and WordPress instance. We are also building a WordPress plugin from where they can log in and authorize the salesforce org access in WordPress. So we need the callback URL to be pointing to the WordPress site, not the salesforce org. Is this possible or any workarounds?

Comment: @rahulgawale, you are asking it at the wrong place. Here is easiest the implementation of your scenario. 

1. Create a Connected App in Salesforce packaging org (or any other org, except scratch org because scratch org get deleted automatically)
2. Register Wordpress call back url in the connected App.
3. Use this connected app's client Id and client sceret to connect wordpress to salesforce.
4. You can use this client Id and sceret to connect any salesforce org from wordpress (not only packaging org).
5. You do not necessarily need to package this connected app (If you want you can do).

Comment: +1 Thanks, @SushantSrivastava.